# how to remove unused javascript functions, variables, and elements

Tags: javascript

is there a firefox addon or something that scans a web document and tells me what javascript thing is not being used? i am doing it manually and its taking forever.

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249/are-there-any-good-javascript-code-coverage-tools

Comment: there was a firefox addon that doesnt work anymore :(

Comment: Don't forget that due to JS' dynamic scripting, results can be easily screwed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could try to use this, if it is possible? At least in Javascript files it is possible. I don't know any good Firefox plugin.

Closure Compiler:
http://code.google.com/intl/fi/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html#removal

Comment: link is broken .