# Superfluous JS and CSS file

Tags: javascript, css, web

I took a very heavy website of my friend and made a few changes to make a website for myself. I am able to do the fancy js/css stuff that I wanted to. But I want to remove the js/css files that I do not require. How can I find out which of these files are superfluous? Thanks

Comment: Try removing them one by one and seeing what breaks!

Comment: Duplicate for CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135657/tool-to-identify-unused-css-definitions

Comment: ...And duplicates for JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543179/how-to-remove-unused-javascript-functions-variables-and-elements, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167663/is-there-a-tool-to-remove-unused-methods-in-javascript, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169889/find-unused-javascript-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to find un-used css, you can use [this site](http://unused-css.com/) to get cleaned css OR You can debug with firebug ( http://getfirebug.com/ ). It will show what is used for what and allows you to find out.

and for javascript: Check out [JSCoverage](http://unused-css.com/) .  Generates code coverage statistics that show which lines of a program have been executed (and which have been missed).